# How to remove dotted outline from iframe in Firefox when tabbed

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe

Is it possible to remove the dotted outline from an iframe in Firefox?

Setting the outline property in CSS doesn't work.

HTML:

`<iframe width="50" height="50"/>`

CSS:

`iframe { outline: 0 }`

Here's a jsfiddle that reproduces this issue. http://jsfiddle.net/6sHkw/1/

**Edit**

Sorry guys, I wasn't clear with my question.

With the above jsfiddle, the dotted outline appears if you tab to the iframe.  I would like to make it so that the dotted outline does not appear when you tab to it.  Neither border: 0 nor frameborder=0 works.

Comment: 2 biggest contributors to any kind of outline - outline and border, sometimes box-shadow

Comment: outline/border/frameborder apparently does not work when you tab to the iframe in Firefox.  Can you elaborate on how box-shadow has an effect on dotted lines?

Comment: not dotted lines, but it gives textarea a border look, at least for FF, probably on some other elements too but I only came in contact with textarea

Comment: it seems there isn't a way to remove the tab focus outline on FF. Although I wouldn't worry about this minor outline, I have honestly never tabbed to an iframe

Comment: Having this same issue and I can't find a way to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dotted focus outline is in the document inside the iframe, not on the iframe itself.  You can see the same thing with the main browser viewport as well.

I don't believe you can turn it off via styles. It's an accessibility feature: if people are using tab navigation the assumption is that they want to actually see where they are in the tab order.  Otherwise it quickly gets completely unusable.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following

```
iframe {
    border:0px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6sHkw/4/) works in all browsers.

The fiddle will be blank, as there is no src in the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, border: 0 does not work when you tab to the iframe.  This only happens in Firefox.  Any clue as to why this may be happening?

Comment: @KenHirakawa This is what it looks like in FF.. what do you mean 'tab' to it.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ATdHH.png

Comment: @JoshC he means open the fiddle and press tab, when your focused on the iframe from tabbing, it has an outline

Answer (score 1):

you can also set it from the markup (iframe has a [frameborder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_frameborder.asp) property)

```
<iframe width="50" height="50" frameborder="0"/>
```

[**Working Fiddle**:](http://jsfiddle.net/6sHkw/6/)

**Caution:** this in no longer supported in HTML5, so use CSS styling instead (like the other answers)

Comment: Thanks avrahamcool.  I've tried frameborder, but that doesn't work if you tab to the iframe.