# jquery, on tabbing prevent focus in iframe but not in the input inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mozilla, tabbing

The scenario:

I have a page with form that loads more than 4 iframe. i have no control in this iframe as this is generated by other website(API);

The Iframe has a form and input in it.

in my code

```
<form>
<div class="fields">
    <!--onload iframe will populate this area-->
</div>  

<div class="fields">
    <!--onload iframe will populate this area-->
</div>  

<div class="fields">
    <!--onload iframe will populate this area-->
</div> </form>
```

upon page load this happens

```
<form>
<div class="fields">
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0">
        <html>
            <body>
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text">
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>  

<div class="fields">
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0">
        <html>
            <body>
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text">
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>  

<div class="fields">
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0">
        <html>
            <body>
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text">
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div></form>
```

in chrome: 
when filling up the form, tabbing in chrome does not have any problem. 
e.g click on the first input, then press tab key for next input until you complete the whole form filling up.

but in firefox mozilla:

click on the first input, then tab twice to get the next input. it does not select directly the input fields, it seems it goes to every element.

is there a script to prevent this? like the normal behaviour in chrome?

i have check this [Tabindex to skip iframe but not content inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441739/tabindex-to-skip-iframe-but-not-content-inside)
but my case is different

Comment: any one? i am still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Update - It's important to note that this is a special accessibility feature of Firefox & Safari, i.e. it was implemented like this on purpose.  Your question is in fact linked to this one - [How to remove dotted outline from iframe in Firefox when tabbed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773519/how-to-remove-dotted-outline-from-iframe-in-firefox-when-tabbed/18776590#18776590)

** Ideas on how to work around this..

I ran into this exact same issue today and I found a solution. However, there's two important caveats:

1. The code below shows only a partial solution - i.e. what you asked for - going forward. When the user presses SHIFT + TAB (to go back), they will see the border once again. So, in order to support this fully, you'd need to listen for these keyboard events, send a message 
   to the targeted Iframe, and within that controller focus the input. Also, bear in mind that you'd need to consider different browsers' implementations of this and gracefully handle the differences.
2. You need to be the provider/have full control of the iframe contents, in order to access the contents of the Iframe, attach listeners, get input and focus.

Hence, in your JavaScript controller you can do the following to implement the TAB (go forward) functionality:

```
constructor() {
   ...
   this.input = document.getElementById("yourInputId");
   window.addEventListener("focus", event => {
     event.preventDefault();
     this.input.focus();
   });
}
```

What happens in the snippet above is:

1. Register an event listener on the whole window (meaning the whole iframe in this case)
2. Intercept the body focus event (as far as I understand, Firefox focuses the body of a cross-origin Iframe first. Perhaps to indicate it's a different context).
3. Prevent the default - so not focus
4. Focusing the input directly instead.

Comment: You just made me realize this issue is only happening on firefox, thanks!